# Show all of data comming from mongodb and render it in doT.js templating engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, template-engine

I wanted to extract data from mongodb and pass it to the view. Everything seems to work, but instead of seeing all 10000 records show up I see only one. I feel that I am very close to solving it, but I got stuck... I am using node-mongodb-native, express and dot.js to achieve my goal.

Here is my app.js, look for the app.get() that's where all the action is:

```
    /**
 * Mongo DB
 */
var mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    serverdb = new mongodb.Server('127.0.0.1', 27017, {}),
    dbName = new mongodb.Db('test', serverdb, {});
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var express = require('express'),
    doT = require('doT'),
    app = express.createServer(),
    pub = __dirname + '/public',
    view =  __dirname + '/views';

// Configuration
app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', view);
    app.set('view options', {layout: false});
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.use(app.router);
});

//Simple templating
app.register('.html',doT, {
    compile: function(str, opts){
        return function(locals){
            return str;
        }
    }
});


//----------------- This is where the problem is i think ---------------
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    dbName.open(function (error, client) {
        var collection = new mongodb.Collection(client, 'personnel');
        collection.find().each(function(err, data){
            //Error check
             if (err){return res.end('error!'+err);}
            //Data
             if (data){
                res.render('index.html',{data:data._id});
             } else {
                 res.end();
             }
        });
    });
});
//--------------------------------------------------------------


app.configure('production', function(){
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});
app.listen(3000);
console.log('Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', app.address().port, app.settings.env);
```

And here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{=it.data}}
</body>
</html>
```

Please help if you can. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally found a solution, first I had to change from `each()` to `toArray()` where retrieves my data is retrieved. then I stringify-ed my data. It's not an ideal solution, since I just print out everything as one string as opposed to iterating through the data in the template. I am just glad I am moving in the right direction.

My app.js:

**EDIT**: found even better solution.

```
    //Replace this code with the one in my question to get full file
    //----------------- This is where the problem was ---------------
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        dbName.open(function (error, client) {
            var collection = new mongodb.Collection(client, 'some_collection');
            collection.find().limit(300).toArray(function (err, dataObjArr) {
                var data = '';
                var dataArr = [];
                var i = dataObjArr.length;
                //check for error
                if(err){return res.end('error!'+err);}
                //Data
                if (dataObjArr) {
                    while(i--){
                        dataArr[i] = dataObjArr[i]._id;
                    }
                    data = dataArr.join(' ');
                    res.render('index.html', { returnedData : data });
                }else{
                    res.end();
                }
            });
        });
    });
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
```

my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{=it.returnedData}}
</body>
</html>
```

Like I said, it's not ideal solution, but I think now I have to put advanced features of the templating engine itself to work.

Comment: @scott-pascoe Thanks Scott, I usually more concise when it comes to my spelling and grammar, all your edits are precise. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about dot.js templating engine. But I would guess that your call to `res.render('index.html',{data:data._id});` results in the page being re-rendered for each element in the cursor and you end up with the last rendering of the page.

Comment: Yeah, that's what seems to happen, but it something which is hard for me to overcome. I tried many possibilities, naturally, both in the app.js and in the view. But none of them gave me the right results. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

While iterating, you can store each data into an array or linkedlist. After finish iterating the array, you can `res.render` and pass the array or linkedlist into the view.